# Contact form - PHP Parse error

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

Hope someone could help on this matter. I get an **PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /site/folder/path/test/send_email.php on line 9** on the following code:

```
$email_to =   'email@address.com <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{vars,a,i,j,r,c,l=document.getElementById("__cf_email__");a=l.className;if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>'; //the address to which the email will be sent
$name     =   $_POST['name'];
$email    =   $_POST['email'];
$subject  =   $_POST['subject'];
$message  =   $_POST['message'];

$headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";

if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'sent'; // we are sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the   mail is sent..
}else{
    echo 'failed';// ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent
}
```

Comment: What kind of email address is *that*?

Comment: in other words, escape ' characters, use \' ; you cand do this: $x = 'text'bla bla' bla'; use: $x = 'bla bla\'bla bla bla\'';

Answer (score 2):

Delimit these bits:

```
className;if(a){s=\'\';
```

You start off the string with single quotes with:

```
$email_to =   '...
```

So you need to delimit any further single quotes within the string as above.

Edit: I have indented the code as follows:

```
<?php

$email_to =   'email@address.com <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function()
{try
    {
            vars,a,i,j,r,c,l=document.getElementById("__cf_email__");
            a=l.className;
            if(a)
            {
                s=\'\';
                r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);
                for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2)
                {
                    c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;
                    s+=String.fromCharCode(c);
                }
                s=document.createTextNode(s);
                l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);
            }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
    }
}
)();
/* ]]> */
</script>';

echo 'Something';
?>
```

and I can't see any parse errors in it.

Comment: Thanks. I added the delimits but now seem to get an error on line 6. It says it's an **unexpected T_STRIN**.

Comment: @kolorguild Are you sure that *all* of that is supposed to be in the email_to section rather than the body perhaps?

Comment: I'm new to the PHP mail form game so not sure. Was following a online tut. It also points to a JS file is that's any help?

Comment: @kolorguild You should read read the docs on [PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) which give you loads of info. Short version: Use javascript inside the body, not inside a `to` header.

Comment: @kolorguild No worries, when you fix your code, please do Accept this answer if it has solved your issue. If it was another issue and your question is answered, you might want to edit your question with the solution so that other googlers coming across this might find help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes `\'`:

```
$email_to =   'email@address.com <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{vars,a,i,j,r,c,l=document.getElementById("__cf_email__");a=l.className;if(a){s=\'\';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.pare    ntNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>'; //the address to which the email will be sent
```